# How to remove file associations

Tags: .net, windows, file, registry, associations

I'd like to know what information should be deleted in order to remove program association with particular file extension.

I obviously know that extensions are stored in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT key, but I'm not sure what to delete or keep. Should I remove the entire .EXTENSION key when the program is uninstalled? Should I backup the original data of the key? Or simply clear the default key value (which is the program ID)?

Please advise.

Comment: Certainly restore the original state is great, assuming they still have the application that served it installed. Not to make it even more complicated. ;)

Answer (score 1):

First off, rather than editing HKCR directly, I would recommend you use the built-in [ftype and assoc commands](http://commandwindows.com/assoc.htm). (Even if they change how the Reigstry is arranged, no doubt Microsoft will continue to support these commands doing it the right way.)

I guess what you do with the file association kind of depends on how command the extension is... (You can look up common file extensions [here](http://filext.com/).) If your app uses a rare file extension, then I would say you're safe to remove both the extension association (`assoc .ext=`) and file type (`ftype myfiletype=`).

But if your app registers a common file extension--say, '.TXT'--then you ought to do your best to handle it gracefully. If you wanted to be *really* nice, you could save the existing file associations during the install, and then restore them to those original values during the uninstall. Or in cases like '.TXT' where there's a common default (NOTEPAD.EXE), you could set it back to that. Otherwise, I might just remove the association (`assoc .ext=`) so the next time the user double-clicks on the file it prompts them to pick a program (which will build the ftype values for them).

Comment: @David Good to know... but can you point us to their recommendation?

Comment: I think your problem is that you are searching for Micro$oft for some reason. The company is called Microsoft.

Comment: I am quite aware of how the company's name is spelled. Spelling it with a dollar sign is a little joke. But anyway--back to my question: what is Microsoft's recommendation for file type associations? I have not seen such a spec.

Comment: I don't really find the joke very funny. It's rather offensive. Lots of MS employees are active here. You should edit the answer and make it less insulting.

Comment: I wouldn't consider pointing out that someone has money insulting, but hey... if it offends somebody, I'll remove it.

Comment: MS recommends that you don't shell out to other executables in an installer. Instead you should write to the registry directly. This makes msi packages more malleable.